# Get all record if input parameters is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a function to filter based on CustName and Date (Posted data), I can't find a way to show all data if CustName is empty.

I've tried adding NULL and Empty to my CustName variable, but none seems to work.

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
$custname = $this->input->post('custname');

if ($custname = NULL){

        $this->db->select('t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes')
                ->from('activity as t1')
                ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
                ->where('t2.user_id', $user);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();                        

        if ($result) {
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode([
            'result' => 1,
            'data' => $query->result_array()
        ]));
        return false;
    }        
}
```

here the js:

```
var load_report = function () {
    $("#myreport").submit(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var postData = $(this).serialize();

        $.post(url, postData, function (o) {
            if (o.result == 1) {
                var output = '';
                Result.success('Data has been retrieved');
                for (var i = 0; i < o.data.length; i++) {
                    output += Template.todo(o.data[i]); 
                    $("#usr").html(output);
                }                    

            }else {
                Result.error(o.error);
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
};
```

Expected result when custname field is empty is to show all records based on user_id. 
Actual result it doesn't show anything

Comment: if ($custname == NULL) {

You should use `==` instead `=`

Comment: @Rajesh I changed it but the result still same

Comment: @Rajesh it's working, besides "==" I miss one parenthesis too. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
if ($custname = NULL){
```

to

```
if ($custname == NULL){
```

**=** is used in assigning value, **==** is used in doing equality check